# Blender with Python 3.8

Tags: python, linux

I am new to Blender and Linux in general. I am using Blender on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. The default system python is 3.8. I have a custom python module built with cppyy and python 3.8 and I cannot use it with Blender because it uses python 3.7. Can you tell me, step-by-step (assume I know nothing), how I can either download or build a version of Blender that uses python 3.8? Thank you.

Comment: Blender comes "embedded" with Python 3.7 for a reason or two. Mainly to keep compatibility with [VFX Reference Platform CY2020](https://vfxplatform.com/) and [Pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11).